# What's the correct email attachment MIME type for a zipped and password protected file?

Tags: email, mime-types, 7zip

It's zipped and password protected with 7zip, should the mimetype be "application/7zip", or just "data/binary"?  Something else?

Comment: Just to spell out the hopefully obvious, `data/binary` is a _horribly_ bad guess. If you don't have a more specific MIME type, `application/octet-stream` is the correct way to indicate "here is a bunch of bytes with no further MIME information".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to Wikipedia (7z article), the mime type of a 7zip archive is `application/x-7z-compressed`, having a password on it will not change the mimetype.

If it is a zip (ie. not 7-zip file), the mimetype should be `application/zip`

Comment: Internet media type : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z

Comment: Surprisingly, I cannot find 7z file in IANA Media Types documentation : https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application. Maybe the `x-` stands for extensions/non official mime types ?