# Python EmailMessage().addAttachment; How to attach a ZIP file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, email-attachments, file-type

Basically my question is, how to attach a .zip archive?

```py
msg.add_attachment(fileToAttachData, maintype=, subtype=, filename="Something")
```

**What is the main and the subtype of a .zip archive?**

If you know please tell me because I may need the sub and main type of `.pptx` and `.docx`

Comment: What is `msg`? Why do you need the types of pptx and docx files if you want to attach a zip file?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203400/whats-the-correct-email-attachment-mime-type-for-a-zipped-and-password-protecte

Comment: `msg = EmailMessage()`
And I only want to use .zip when it above a given data size.
If it's just 2 small picture and a document I don't want to compress it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay!
Thanks to the help [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1)!

I found a way to find the most MIME type!
So, in Wikipedia they list it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_(computing)

At the right side, you can see the Internet media type which is `maintype`/`subtype`
For example, Word is `application/msword`!

You can find some common examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Common_examples